# How best to maintain incremental counter value when app is reopened

Tags: swift, uniqueidentifier

I have a struct that requires a unique id for each new instance. I am not using UUID as I need it to be sequential 1, 2, 3 ...

I am currently doing this using:

```
private static var idSequence = sequence(first: 1, next: {$0 + 1})
```

And this works if the app remains open. However, my problem with this is that when I reopen the app, the sequence starts from 1 again rather than the next sequence after the last one used.

```
class Transactions: ObservableObject {   
    @Published var buyTransactions = [BuyTransaction]() {
        didSet {
            writeFile() // When buyTransactions state changes, save those changes to file
        }
    }
    
    @Published var sellTransactions: [SellTransaction]() {
        didSet {
            writeFile() // When sellTransactions state changes, save those changes to file
        }
    }

    init() {
        readFile() // When Transactions is first initialised, load saved transactions into arrays
    }
}

struct BuyTransaction: Identifiable, Codable {
    private static var idSequence = sequence(first: 1, next: {$0 + 1})
    
    let id: Int
    let dateTime: Date
    let someOtherValue: String
    
    init?(
        dateTime: Date,
        someOtherValue: String
    ) {
        guard let id = BuyTransaction.idSequence.next() else { return nil }
        
        self.id = id
        self.dateTime = dateTime
        self.someOtherValue: someOtherValue
    }
}

struct SellTransaction: Identifiable, Codable {
    private static var idSequence = sequence(first: 1, next: {$0 + 1})
    
    let id: Int
    let dateTime: Date
    let someOtherValue: String
    let andMoreValues: String
    
    init?(
        dateTime: Date,
        someOtherValue: String
        andMoreValues: String
    ) {
        guard let id = BuyTransaction.idSequence.next() else { return nil }
        
        self.id = id
        self.dateTime = dateTime
        self.someOtherValue: someOtherValue
        self.andMoreValues: andMoreValues
    }
}
```

I don't see how I can replace the 1 with a variable:

```
private static var idSequence = sequence(first: nextID, next: {$0 + 1})
```

because i'm not sure how to set nextID before the object instance of BuyTransaction or SellTransaction is initialised

I've thought about storing a copy of the last id in a separate file and read it into a global static variable when the object is first initialised or to save it to UserDefaults but I'm not sure if these ideas are best practice.

Is anyone able to provide an example of how best to resolve this? Maybe there is a better way than what I have tried to do here.

There's probably an obvious solution, but I am new to swift and writing an app with a real purpose as a learning tool, so I haven't been able to figure it out for myself.

Comment: If you really need sequential numbering, then you have no choice but to store the last assigned ID somewhere. This is the classic use case of UserDefaults.

Comment: Since you need data to survive program restarts, you *need* some external storage, probably a simple file is the easiest, otherwise save it alongside your program settings or in your database if you happen to have one. Then re-read that value again on startup so you can restore the counter value.

Comment: Okay so either UserDefaults or stored in a file are both suitable options?

Comment: The implementation of UserDefaults uses a file. Don't worry, just use UserDefaults. It's simple and designed exactly for your use case.

Comment: If you want to save just an `Integer` (ie, a small value in term of bytes length, not a whole image of 200MB) and the data is not critical (private like passwords, etc.), then `UserDefaults` is a good solution for that.

Comment: You may use just a monotonic function (in a mathematical sense), for example using a time value. Of course, in practice it is not guaranteed this function is monotonic after a restart of the system, but IMHO, still better than to rely on UserDefaults or other presistent storages (because these can be deleted). A better solution would probably be time ordered UUIDs: https://forums.swift.org/t/uniqueid-time-ordered-uuids-in-swift/53265

Comment: Thanks all, UserDefaults is doing the job!